# Need help in online application cloud based

Tags: cloud

I am working on online application which my clients will use on monthly bases.
I have already purchase cloud server. I will also provide hosting services as well

But i am confused at one point.
Lets suppose 100 uses have registered and apply for my application.

So do i need to go and install my application on each of the user domain name manually?
i.e 100 in our case

Or should i create centralize application where i just give them user name and password and then they have their own back end application?

Hope that make sense!

Which is easy to implement?
How to procced further ?

Pls guide me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [SAAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) paradigm seems to suite you well. instead of deploying, maintaining and supporting your application on every customer's site, you can provide them with credentials so they consume the application online. your clients will benefit from this paradigm as well, since they won't need the hardware to deploy your application on-site. you should think of scalability and elasticity when developing your application.